# how to copy a value from input to another selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

If i change the next input:

```
<input type="text" value="100000" name="value1" id="value1">
```

The value should also change in:

```
<span class="value2">100000</span>
```

i tried with this, but not working:

```
(function ($) {
    var $change = $(".value2");
    $("#value1").keyup(function () {
        $change.val(this.value);
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: `val()` works for input fields. check for http://api.jquery.com/text/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.text`

```
$change.text( this.value );
```

**Span does not support `.val` method**

It only works on `form elements.`

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/8ghCT/)**

Answer (score 0):

spans don't have a value - only input elements do. Use `.text(this.value)` instead:

```
(function($) {
    var $change = $(".value2");

    $("#value1").keyup(function() {
        $change.text(this.value);
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

`$change.val( this.value );`

Should be:

`$change.text( this.value );`

Since `<span>` doesn't have a `.val()`